# How to call startActivityForResult from static method?

Tags: android

My question seems to be duplicated but it is not. I have searched hours to find a solution but I found no help.

I need call startActivityForResult from static method.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Activity context to the static method and call `startActivityForResult` on that.

```
public static void CallMethod(Activity activity)
{
    // create intent
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode); // use your intent and code
}
```

Comment: startActivityForResult is not a method of Context

Comment: Thank you. As Blackbelt said startActivityForResult is not a method of Context.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant activity context. Updated.

Comment: Thank you Rohit5k2. I have tried so many times, But I was not able to find the right answer. I was unable to pass activity to the static method.